# Cast to super class type a "Class"

Tags: java, inheritance, encapsulation

I have an interface

```
interface Inter extends Blah {
   public void someMethod();
}

class Dummy {
  Class<Blah> interfaceType;

  public setInterfaceType( Class<Blah> input ) {
    this.interfaceType = input;
  }  
}

class tester {
  public void init() {
    Dummy dummyObj = new DummyObj();
    dummyObj.setInterfaceType( Inter.class );     //This complains that the type is not suitable
  }
}
```

Compilation error:

> The method setInterfaceType(Class) in the type Dummy is not applicable for the arguments (Class)

I tried casting `input` to `Class<Blah>` while calling setter but that isnt allowed either. Im not understanding why it doesnt accept a class of sub-class-type. Can anyone tell me whats happening here and how the setter can be invoked. The `Dummy` class is external so i cannot change it.

Comment: Generics inheritance behaves different. You need to use wildcards to achieve what you are looking for http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Generics are not covariant](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html) so you can't set to `Class<Blah>` object of type `Class<Inter>`. Think about it. If you would be able to use `List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<Apple>()` then via `list` you would be able to add not only Apples but also other Fruits. Would that be OK?

To solve this problem try changing `Class<Blah>` to `Class<? extends Blah>`

You can also change your `Dummy` class to use generic type `T`

```
class class Dummy<T extends Blah> {
    Class<T> interfaceType;

    public void setInterfaceType(Class<T> input) {
        this.interfaceType = input;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
Dummy<Inter> dummyObj = new Dummy();
dummyObj.setInterfaceType(Inter.class);
```

Comment: Nice, it worked. I had to create a variable of type Class<? extends Blah> and then cast it to Class<Blah> while invoking the setter. and it compiles fine now. Thanks

Comment: The Dummy class is an external lib so cant change it, but your hint worked.

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly means

```
Class<? extends Blah> interfaceType;

public setInterfaceType( Class<? extends Blah> input ) {
    this.interfaceType = input;
}
```

**Update**

If the Dummy class can't be modified, then it is pretty dubius WHY there is such a setter method. But anyway, you may avoid the "generic type" check, by casting your argument to Class (without type argument), as in: dummyObj.setInterfaceType( (Class) Inter.class )

Comment: That's not entirely true (that it's dubious). It's not uncommon at all for a proxy to have a property that is the interface it proxies, example: org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/source/browse/sub-projects/mybatis-spring/trunk/src/main/java/org/mybatis/spring/mapper/MapperFactoryBean.java?r=3172

Comment: In MapperFactoryBean, T might be any class, so the setMapperInterface does make sense: the MapperFactoryBean class has absolutely no way to gain knowledge of the class it is working with. In the OP though, Dummy.setInterfaceType() expect to be given the object Blah.class, and _nothing else_. That is, not the class object of any class (or other interface) that implements (or extends) it. And a proxy class _is a distinct class_ that implements the interface given as argument. So Dummy was able to obtain the Blah.class object by itself, without any need for the setter.